# Always `$newline never` in Yesod

Tags: haskell, widget, newline, yesod, hamlet

`$newline never` in Hamlet allows us to minify the HTML code. If we set it in a parent widget, it takes effect on it but not on the child widgets. So we have to set `$newline never` to all of the widgets when we want to minify the whole code. This isn't good.

Don't you know any better solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own Hamlet quasi-quoter that defaults to `NoNewlines` in its `HamletSettings`, like the following (untested) code snippet:

```
import Text.Hamlet

myHamlet :: QuasiQuoter
myHamlet = hamletWithSettings hamletRules defaultHamletSettings{ hamletNewlines = NoNewlines}
```

and then simply use it as `[myHamlet| ... |]`.

Comment: Fun fact: the word "Hamlet" has lost all meaning to me while writing the above answer due to [semantic satiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation)...